# Can't find packages ionic-native/splash-screen and ionic-native/status-bar

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, splash-screen, ionic-native

my issue is clearly defined. I'm unable to install or use these two mentioned packages in my project. For example, check out my stackblitz.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-mz5zug

If I go to install them, the workspace gives me message:

```
Failure: Package Not Found.
```

This happening for both packages. Compatibility issues with angular and/or the other ionic packages? What's the error here?
Can you fix it in my stackblitz?

** check out package.json carefully. Whatever installation and uninstallations I did, the history is mentioned there.

Looking for exact, precise answer.

Comment: I don't know if it's just a typo in the title, but the "@" is actually part of the packages name. I recommend you visit the package page on npmjs.com.

Comment: Looks like Issue with your Project and Ionic CLI Version. Upgrade to latest IONIC version and create a fresh project and check. 
After analysing you stackblitz you are using older version of ionic i.e 3.9.2 which is way older. 
Check this updated stackblitz and fork it for your usage.   https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-angular-v5-a6dste?

Comment: hey   @NajamUsSaqib         ok, let me check this,

Answer (score 0):

Version Compatibility.

You're trying to install the latest version of ionic-native (which uses angular 11.2 as a dependency) on your Angular 5.2.9 project.

You should either upgrade your project, or downgrade ionic native.
If you choose to downgrade ionic-native you would probably want to use version `5.0.0-beta.6`

```
"@ionic-native/core": "5.0.0-beta.6",
"@ionic-native/splash-screen": "5.0.0-beta.6",
"@ionic-native/status-bar": "5.0.0-beta.6",
```

Comment: Version compatibility wouldn't geive "package not found" error. from what I understood he is having a problem getting the package

Comment: @Haythem    installed the packages. Used @ and installed fine. Trouble is Same Error Persists, if you check the stackblitz. Nothing changes.

Comment: Hi @Stavm 

I updated the stackblitz. the splash-screen and status-bar packages now are installed. Versions 5.3.4.0. That complies with what you suggested ie     5.0.0-beta.6. But error is the same still, if you check the stackblitz; what do you recommend  ?

Install Missing Dependencies.

Comment: I don't understand why you are insisting on the stackblitz when you are having an error about packages unfound. A package must be found by the application in 3 forms, as an actual package in your node_modules folder, and in package.json for the naming and versioning and finally in your component for the actual use. try checking node_modules, running npm i and npm audit. whatever your problem is, it's not code related from what I see, unless I am missing something.

Comment: stackblitz as reference because I am replicating part of my actual case there as any SO user, who posts their questions will tell u.


let me see, what is    @Haythem